# Iterate a set containing vectors without using any range based loops or reference to a vector

Tags: c++, loops, vector, iterator, set

Suppose I have a set containing n vectors  of different sizes.
I want to iterate them without using any ranged based loops.
How will I do it! 

//For example this works but I have used range based loops here

```
set < vector <int> > fset;
    for(auto it : fset)
        {
            for(auto itt : it)
            cout << itt << " ";
            cout << endl;
        }
```

//This too works but I have used a i as a vector reference and iterated index wise

```
set < vector <int> > fset;
for(set < vector <int> > :: iterator it=fset.begin();it!=fset.end();++it)
    {
        const vector < int >& i = (*it);
        int l = i.size();
        for(int j=0; j<l; ++j)
        cout << i[j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
```

I want to display all the vector contents line by line present in the set but without using any of the above mentioned methods.
Please help me how will I do it!
Thankyou!

Comment: Would this be your homework?

Comment: You just used an iterator for the set, do it for the underlying vector too, done.

Comment: I'm new to learning stl in cpp and I tried that but I'm getting error! @Gill Bates

Comment: @MoinakDebnath: use `it->begin()` when you write the `for` of `vector`.

Comment: I have used @lorro still getting compilation error!

Comment: @MoinakDebnath: kindly post your efforts (in the original post to have formattings) so we can help. Also tell us what error you're getting.

Comment: Questions like this always puzzle me. I want to do X, but not in any way that the language is designed to let you do X. So then, what are you _really_ trying to accomplish? Perhaps we can help you with that.

Comment: @Duthomhas I was trying to iterate the vector using a iterator but Its not working out , I tried it in an online IDE and its giving CE.

Comment: What does “CE” mean?

Comment: @duthomhas CE means  compilation error

Comment: Compilation errors mean you made a mistake somewhere. For example, in the second codes you presented above you use a variable `j` that has never been declared. Figure out what the first error is, fix your code to be correct, and try again. Repeat until it compiles.

Comment: no the error is related to the vector iterator not the one you pointed.
thnx any way Im changing that in the question! @Duthomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, this should print your set of vectors:

```
set <vector <int> > data;

for (const auto& row : data)
{
  for (int value : row)
    cout << value << ", ";
  cout << "\n";
}
```

You can easily adjust the formatting between elements of a vector in the inner loop, and anything you want at the beginning or end of the line before or after the inner loop.

Using iterators:

```
for (auto row_it = data.begin(); row_it != data.end(); ++row_it)
{
  for (auto value_it = row_it->begin(); value_it != row_it->end(); ++value_it)
    cout << *value_it << ", ";
  cout << "\n";
}
```

These two things do the exact same thing. The ranged-for only adds a level of indirection by adding something like

```
int value = *value_it;
```

at the beginning of the inner loop.

Hope this helps.

(oops. Fixed typo.)

**Final edit**
I'm guessing you are stuck with an older C++ compiler (C++98 or C++03, which is basically the same thing) if you want to avoid `auto`.

To name the iterators properly, you need to think about the type they represent. Something that is non-obvious here, just looking at the code, is that ***you may not modify the set's values***. Therefore, all the inner iterators must be `const`.

But, since you are only printing the set itself, you might as well be explicit and use a const iterator for the outer loop as well.

```
for (set <vector <int> > ::const_iterator row_it = data.begin();  row_it != data.end();  ++row_it)
{
  for (vector <int> ::const_iterator value_it = row_it->begin();  value_it != row_it->end();  ++value_it)
    cout << *value_it << ", ";
  cout << "\n";
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: What did you not understand about "I want to iterate them without using any ranged based loops."?

Comment: I want to use an iterator for the set as well as for the vector and display all of them. I tried to iterate the vector but Im getting compilation error in an online IDE.
Actually using ranged based loops is easy but without using it we have to know how the iterator works, that is why. @GillBates

Comment: What did you not understand about actual problem solving? I'm trying to help the OP solve their problem, not be a jerk and only answer their question with the most literal possible response. OP clearly wants to print the set, and is struggling to do it.

Comment: @duthomhas thank you sir but If I dont use the "auto" as my iterator type what should I write ?
As before I declared the iterator  as vector type not as auto so I was getting compilation error!

Comment: @Dúthomhas  : sir if I dont want to use auto as my iterator type , what type of iterator type for the vector should i declare, previously I declared it as vector < int> :: iterator value_it so I was getting compilation error in the online IDE. pls help and thnx in advance.

Comment: @Dúthomhas : thank you for your help! I guess I couldn't explain where my doubt was , thats why I have got a down vote to my question. But Actually i did not wish to use the auto type iterator and iterate the vector.Hence your explanation finally cleared my doubt and just because I didnt use const_iterator it gave compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

Requires C++14 (but easily convertible to C++11 as well)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::set<std::vector<int>> svec = {
    {1,2,3},
    {4,5,6}
  };
  std::for_each(std::begin(svec), std::end(svec),
              [](const auto& vec) {
                  std::copy(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec),
                            std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
                  std::cout << '\n';
              });
  return 0;
}
```